# Jquery check if parent has an ID

Tags: jquery

Hi i'm trying to check if a parent element contains an ID

Here is my list

```html
<ul>
<li></li>
<li id="selected">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Don't know how to make a correct list in here?

```
if (jQuery(LiElement).parent("#selected"))
{
    //If parent has id=selected
}
else
{
    //If parent dont have id=selected
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Are you actually typing out HTML tags with parentheses?  Should be `<ul> <li></li></ul>`...

Comment: @Squirkly: No, he didn't understand the "101010" button, or the code indention trick for getting it to display correctly.

Comment: I see.  I've never seen it output like that.

Comment: How are you triggering your check?  Are you wanting this to happen for each `<li>` element on page load, or are they being check `onclick` or something else?

Comment: immediate parent or ancestor?

Answer (score 23):

You could test the `length` property of the `.parent("#selected")`:

```
if( Query(LiElement).parent("#selected").length )
```

If the parent has the `#selected` ID, it will return `1` (true), otherwise `0` (false).

*Note that you are testing the immediate parent only. I think this is what you wanted.*

If the ID is not the immediate parent, you could use `closest()` to test any ancestor for the ID.

```
if( Query(LiElement).closest("#selected").length )
```

Just be aware that this will also test the *current* element.

Comment: +1 for .closest(), probably what is needed, but poster will have to decide.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).parent('#selected').length) {
    ⋮
    } else {
    ⋮
    }
});
```

works great for me.

Comment: Note to beginners: when not found in parents it will be of length 0, zero means false when evaluated as boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Not positive, but I think it should just be

```
if ($('li').parents('#selected')) {...} else {...}
```

Comment: You need to test .length; .parents() will always return a jQuery object (even if nothing matches) which will evaluate to true